# As shown in the figure: Prove that $a\,+\,b\,+\,c=d$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Geometry: Auxiliary Lines

As shown in the figure: Prove that $a\,+\,b\,+\,c=d$
[image]

Comment: Why do you say "buildings in the triangle" in all your geometry questions? I don't think it means whatever you think it means.

Comment: @Rahul Narain solutions such as none  without using trigonometry:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223893/as-shown-in-the-figure-prove-that-a2b2-c2

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. But assuming you're Spanish, I guess when you say *building* you mean a *construcción* in geometry; this is called a *geometrical [construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge_constructions)* in English. The word *[building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building)* is only used for a *construcción* in the architectural sense.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Using sine law of triangle, $$\frac e{\sin(144^{\circ}-x)}=\frac g{\sin 36^{\circ}}$$ and $$\frac e{\sin(138^{\circ}-x)}=\frac {g+f}{\sin 42^{\circ}}$$

So, $$f=e\left(\frac{\sin 42^{\circ}}{\sin(138^{\circ}-x)}-\frac{\sin 36^{\circ}}{\sin(144^{\circ}-x)}\right)$$

$$=e\left(\frac{\sin 42^{\circ}\sin(144^{\circ}-x)-\sin 36^{\circ}\sin(138^{\circ}-x)}{\sin(138^{\circ}-x)\sin(144^{\circ}-x)}\right)$$

$2\sin 42^{\circ}\sin(144^{\circ}-x)$
$=\cos(102^{\circ}-x)-\cos({186^\circ}-x)$ using $2\sin A\sin B$
$=\cos(102^{\circ}-x)+\cos(6^\circ-x)$ as $\cos(180^{\circ}+y)=-\cos y$

$2\sin 36^{\circ}\sin(138^{\circ}-x)=\cos(102^{\circ}-x)-\cos({174^\circ}-x)$
$=\cos(102^{\circ}-x)+\cos(6^\circ+x)$ as $\cos({174^\circ}-x)=\cos\{180^\circ-(6^\circ+x)\}=-\cos(6^\circ+x)$

So, $$f=e\frac{\cos(6^\circ-x)-\cos(6^\circ+x)}{2\sin(138^{\circ}-x)\sin(144^{\circ}-x)}=\frac{e\sin x\sin 6^\circ }{\sin(138^{\circ}-x)\sin(144^{\circ}-x)}$$

For $f=a, x=12^\circ, a=\frac{e\sin 12^\circ\sin 6^\circ }{\sin126^{\circ}\sin132^{\circ}}$

For $f=b, x=60^\circ, b=\frac{e\sin 60^\circ\sin 6^\circ }{\sin78^{\circ}\sin84^{\circ}}$

For $f=c, x=96^\circ, c=\frac{e\sin 96^\circ\sin 6^\circ }{\sin42^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}}$

$2\sin42^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}=\cos 6^\circ -\cos 90^\circ=\cos 6^\circ$

and $\sin 96^\circ=\sin(90+6)^\circ=\cos 6^\circ$

So,$ c=2e\sin 6^\circ $

For $f=d, x=108^\circ, d=\frac{e\sin 108^\circ\sin 6^\circ }{\sin30^{\circ}\sin36^{\circ}}=\frac{2e\sin 72^\circ\sin 6^\circ }{\sin36^{\circ}}=4e\cos 36^\circ \sin 6^\circ$